# Changing the Length of drawn polyline : leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am fairly new in using leaflet. Can someone tell me how to change the length of already drawn polyline in leaflet?. I want to make its length small or large depending on zoom level.

Comment: Well a polyline is a collection of points, which are (Latitude, Longitude) pairs. You could, in theory, extend a polyline by tacking on an additional point X distance left of the end of your current polyline and rerender it. Whether this is doable in Leaflet I'm not sure, but programmatically it's not a difficult task.

Comment: This is unclear. What do you want to achieve? Do you have any screenshots of how the final result should look like?

Comment: I dont have screenshot but I mean that whenever I zoom in it should become short and whenever I zoom out it becomes long as it is so that polyline fits on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaflet polyline is a array of  points, each of them consist of lat and lng. To change it's size you need to update this array and change distance between points width `setLatLngs()` method.

If you want to fit the screen you need to get screen bounding box width `map.getBounds()` get lat or lng from bbox and update your line width it.

So it will be something like this:

```
 map.on('zoomend', function(){
   var bounds = map.getBounds();
   line.setLatLngs(bounds[0],bounds[1]);
 })
```